Calculate the range of a dynamic array that can be used as an argument in the linest function
The following expression works well in excel, but I would like to implement it in vba:
=SERIESSUM(F14,B9,-1,TRANSPOSE(LINEST(FILTER(G6:G45,G6:G45>0),FILTER(F6:F45,G6:G45>0)^SEQUENCE(1,B9,1,1))))^3

In the above, B9, F6:F45 are fixed, but:
F14 will be replaced with a variable x that will execute the function within a loop for each cell Sheets("data").cells(6,x) in the range F6:F45, and
The function will be called with G6:G45 replaced with ranges from G6:G45, H6:H45 ... to Y6:Y45.
I'm familiar with the use of WorksheetFunction.(some function) in vba.
My first problem is FILTER, which has different arguments in VBA from those in Excel, preventing me from using it as I'd like. It's also not available in early versions of Excel, which will be a problem for some users. The values in G6:G45 to Y6:Y45 start and end with varying numbers of  consecutive zeroes. I want to select the non-zero (as double) values between these groups of zeroes (which happen to always be greater than zero).
How can I do this? I've gone through the lists of existing posts and have had problems with making promising examples work.
I would be happy to hear further recommendations about how to implement the excel function in VBA, but am happy to try that myself once I know how to replace the FILTER function.
I was expecting FILTER to have the same arguments in VBA as in Excel, but it does not. I can't get it to perform the same function in VBA as in Excel, and FILTER is not available in earlier versions of excel.

Please edit your question to include a sample of your data as text as well as the expected output from that data.

A lot of issues for one post.
You don't need the SERIESSUM function for the calculations you want to perform, because there is a specialized TREND function that will return the entire array at once, without the need for loops. The equivalent of the given formula would be:
=TREND(FILTER(G6:G45,G6:G45>0),FILTER(F6:F45,G6:G45>0)^SEQUENCE(1,B9))^3

The formula is dynamic, returning the entire set of values at once.
When it comes to generating these results using VBA, there are at least two ways of implementation:

using Excel functions typed into cells via VBA and then possibly converted into values, e.g.

With Range("G50")
    .Formula2 = _
    "=TREND(FILTER(G6:G45,G6:G45>0),FILTER(F6:F45,G6:G45>0)^SEQUENCE(1,B9))^3"
    .SpillingToRange.Value = .SpillingToRange.Value
End With

using the WorksheetFunction (or Application) method – then we get the values right away, but there is a problem with operations on arrays.
In VBA you cannot produce array results with operators like +, - , *,  /, ^ and relations like =, >. You must use appropriate functions instead. It may be problematic.
An example below:

    Dim n As Long, crit As Variant
    With Application
        n = .CountIf(Range("G6:G45"), ">0")
        crit = .GeStep(Range("G6:G45").Value, 0.0001)
        Range("G50").Resize(n).Value = _
            .Power(.Trend(.Filter(Range("G6:G45").Value, crit), _
            .Power(.Filter(Range("F6:F45").Value, crit), _
            .Sequence(1, Range("B9").Value))), 3)
    End With
The GESTEP function verifies relation >=. If you need > you must use very small number as criterion according to your data.
There is also a third one – using the Evaluate method, but you probably haven't thought about this method.
As for the FILTER function, it has exactly the same arguments in VBA as in Excel, it can't be otherwise. The problem lies elsewhere. The function has array arguments, and in VBA (using WorksheetFunction) you can't perform operations on arrays as easily as in Excel. It has been shown above.
If you are looking for a replacement for the FILTER function to work in earlier versions of Excel, you can use the INDEX and MATCH functions, but the formulas will be longer. Besides, the SEQUENCE function would also have to be replaced, but you don't ask about it, so I guess you know that.
Equivalent of FILTER in earlier Excel (for the case of continuous series of positive numbers) may be this:
=INDEX(G6:G45,MATCH(TRUE,G6:G45>0,0)):INDEX(G6:G45;MATCH(2,1/(G6:G45>0)))

In VBA you can use the code:
Dim n As Long, crit As Variant, srcx As Range, srcy As Range
Dim filtx As Range, filty As Range
With Application
    Set srcx = Range("F6:F45")
    Set srcy = Range("G6:G45")
    n = .CountIf(srcy, ">0")
    crit = .GeStep(srcy.Value, 0.0001)
    Set filtx = Range(.Index(srcx, .Match(1, crit, 0)), .Index(srcx, .Match(2, .Power(crit, -1))))
    Set filty = Range(.Index(srcy, .Match(1, crit, 0)), .Index(srcy, .Match(2, .Power(crit, -1))))
    Range("G50").Resize(n).Value = _
        .Power(.Trend(filty, .Power(filtx, .Sequence(1, Range("B9").Value))), 3)
End With

Update
An illustration of how to use the TREND function on the example of a 5th degree polynomial.

Update 2
An illustration to the question from comments.
How to use the TREND function for the quadratic polynomial.
You can involve the column with x^2 however it is not necessary.


Thanks for your detailed reply.
Reading up on what TREND does is frustrating. What are the significances of the returned values of TREND(known_y’s, known_x’s )?
And when I try an example of of a 7th oredr polynomial in Excel rather than VBA, its accuracy is underwhelming, Typically errors are a few percent. LINEST gives much more accurate results.

If you use only 2 arguments, the TREND function returns array result evaluated for the same arguments that you specified as known_x. You can specify other arguments as the third argument new_x. The results are the same as if you were to create a polynomial based on the coefficients calculated by LINEST. The results in Excel and VBA must be identical. If there are differences, it means that there is a mistake somewhere.

Of course, if known_x is just a single column, then you will get a linear function, as in the case of LINEST. If you need a polynomial regression, the known_x must be raised to the appropriate powers, e.g. known_x^sequence(1,4) with a polynomial of the 4th degree. If we use new_x, then the same power exponents must be used.
If something doesn't work out, give examples of data and show what you have a problem with.

I'm making progress using LINEST in VBA using defined 1D and 2D arrays; don't know what to do with TREND. TREND( , ) gives very different results from LINEST, and I do need the coefficients that come from LINEST. I'll use them in different ways. I thank you for your help. I may be back with more questions, but for now, I don't have any except how do I add code to a comment? I don't have a personal http:// site.

TREND gives the same results as SERIESSUM+LINEST (TRANSPOSE is needless). Of course you can calculate coefficients from LINEST if you need them for different calculations.
I'm afraid that you won't be able to add a code to the comment (at most a very short one), but you can add example data and expected results to the content of the post. Alternatively, write a new post if you can't edit the first one.

I need the coefficients of power series polynomials of various orders, which I will use in a number of different ways. I know how to get these with LINEST. When I tried TREND(know_y's, known_x's), I don't know what I'm getting, but it' doesn't seem to be those. Several googles of TREND were not helpful. Do you have a description of the significance of the output of TREND(know_y's, known_x's)?

I have added an illustration of how to use TREND function for a polynomial. It is compared to SERIESSUM + LINEST.

In your example, what are "results"? The output of LINEST? Is there some way I can thank you for your help?

Yes, results means output of LINEST.

I'm unable to get Trend to work with a power series.

I'm unable to get Trend to work with a power series. known_y's = .32 .55 .73 .88. known_x's  20 40 60 80. TREND(known_y's, known_x's) = .34 1 .527 .713 .899.   If I expand the known_x's array to add a second column whose values are squares of the first: 400 1600 3600 6400, TREND returns #REF!

The second update with explanation. I hope it is clear now.
